# codeigniter loading models list errors

Tags: codeigniter, model

i am loading some models in my controller so i can use them in my view but there is a weird problem going on which doesnt allow me to load model1 above model2 and throws an error... if i switch how i load them it will work fine...

ex.

```
$this->load->model("model1");
$this->load->model("model2");
```

gives an error that model1 doesnt load so below when i call a function from model1 model it throws an error.

```
$this->load->model("model2");
$this->load->model("model1");
```

works.

Comment: can you please paste in the exact error that's being shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was extending CI_Controller in some of my models and not CI_Model... it seems to be working now...